# how to merge branch into master on the created commit

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch, git-rebase

I have this senario that i created a branch A from master where the master head was on `1234` commit id

and now some developers pushed more branchs and commits into master and now the master head is on `789` commit id.

Is it possible to merging the branch A into master on the commit `1234` ?

Comment: You can use "reset" command to restore old version and then insert your code. But.. you will need to reinsert the "new code"

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to push this analogy too far (because it will break down) but that's a bit like asking if you can get your package onto the cargo ship in China now that the ship is in port in LA.  You can, but you'll have to get the ship back to China first somehow.

Instead of the above klunky analogy, let's look at how Git really works.  Git is all about commits, and—as you've correctly described here—these commits are *numbered*.  The number aren't simple, sequential counting numbers, though—commit #52 is not followed by commit #53 for instance—but instead they're big, ugly, random-looking hash IDs.  So I like to represent them with single uppercase letters instead:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
```

Here, the *name* `master` points to commit `H`.  `H` is the *latest commit that is on `master`*.  Commit `H` itself reaches backwards to earlier commit `G`, which reaches backwards to yet another earlier commit, and so on.

In your case, you created a new name *also pointing to commit `H`* and then made some new commits:

```
          I--J   <-- your-branch
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
```

Unfortunately for you, since then, someone else has added more commits *to* `master`, like this:

```
          I--J   <-- your-branch
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- master
```

You're now asking about using `git merge`.

#### Merging is about *combining work*

When we do use `git merge`, we do this because we'd like to *combine work*.  That is, you started with commit `H`—some particular set of files, stored forever in a commit with some big ugly hash ID.  You changed a file or two and made a new commit, which got some other big ugly random-looking ID that I'm calling `I`, and maybe changed yet another file or two (or the same file or two) and made another commit `J`.  So between `H` and `J`, you did some work, resulting in some changes to some files.

Git can *show you what you did* (summarized into one big all-at-once set of changes) by comparing the snapshot in commit `H`—the set of files frozen for all time from which you started—to the snapshot in your latest commit, `I`.  This will have instructions like: *in file `main.py`, delete line 47, and add some lines after line 300*.

Git can also *show you what other people did* by comparing what's in the snapshot in `H`—note that this snapshot is *shared on both branches*—with what's in the latest snapshot on `master`, in commit `K`.  This may have instructions like *change line 7 in `README.md`*, along with instructions like *add a line at line 100 in `main.py`*.

What `git merge` can do for you—or anyone—is to *combine these changes*.  That is, if they touched `README.md` and you didn't, Git will keep their changes.  If you touched `Documentation/info.md` and they didn't, Git will keep your changes.  If you and they both modified `main.py`, Git will *try* to keep *both sets of changes* to that one file.

If Git *can* combine all these changes on its own, Git will make a single new commit on its own.  This new commit will have, as its snapshot, all the files from the snapshot in `H`—the common starting point—with the *combined changes* applied, so that Git keeps your changes and adds theirs, or—if you prefer to look at it this way—keeps their changes and adds yours.  The result is the same either way, and it looks like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M
         \    /
          K--L
```

What I've left off here is which *branch* holds the new commit `M`.  There are two *names*—`master` and `your-branch`—and Git will only update *one* of these two names so that it points to new commit `M`.  The other name will continue to point to either commit `J`, or to commit `L` (whichever one it pointed-to before).

I've also left off another detail, which sometimes does matter: since commit `M` has *two* backwards links, or *parents*, pointing to commits `J` and `L` both, one of these two comes first.  The other one is second, although for Git, that's just "not first".  The `--first-parent` flag, later, can sometimes be useful to pick out the "first" parent.  The *snapshot* in `M` is the same, no matter how you do the merge, but the choice of first-parent depends on which branch you `git switch` to, and which name you give to `git merge`:

```
git switch master
git merge your-branch
```

gives us:

```
          I--J   <-- your-branch
         /    \₂
...--G--H      M   <-- master
         \    /¹
          K--L
```

That is, `master` is the *name* that moves to point to `M`, and the *first* parent is now `L`.

This is usually what most people want to do—unless, that is, they want to use `git rebase`.

> Is it possible to merging [my branch] into master on the [shared] commit?

Not exactly, because no matter what you do, `master` needs to point to some commit *other* than `H` in the end.

You *can* "eject" commits `K-L`, like this:

```
          I--J   <-- your-branch
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K--L   [abandoned]
```

The problem with doing this is that commits `K` and `L` are now *lost*.  They're not *gone*—they are still there in the repository—but Git *finds* commits by starting with branch names.  The name `master` used to find commit `L`.  From `L`, Git could work backwards to `K`.

Git is unable to work *forwards*.  Git always works *backwards*.  So once you move `master` back two steps, to point to `H`, Git can't find `K` any more.  Even if Git *could* find `K`, that would not help to find `L`.  So these two commits are now "abandoned".  This *throws away their work*.  That's not what merging is for: merging is useful to *keep someone else's work while adding yours*, or, equivalently, to *keep your work while adding someone else's*.

#### Rebasing

Without going into a lot of detail, the idea behind *rebasing* is that we wish to *copy* some set of commits to some new-and-improved commits.  In this particular case, you might wish to take your `I-J` commits, which you think are pretty good, and "improve" them by making two *new* commits—which for no as-yet obvious reason, we'll call `I'` (I-prime) and `J'`—that are a whole lot *like* `I` and `J`.

The difference between the new and improved `I'`, and the original `I`, is in two parts:

- The new `I'` will link backwards not to `H`, but to `K`.
- The new `I'` will have, as its snapshot, not the snapshot in `H` modified with your changes, but rather the snapshot in `K` modified with your changes.

The *rest* of `I'` will be exactly the same as `I`, including the *commit log message*.  Let's draw `I'` now:

```
          I--J   <-- your-branch
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- master
              \
               I'  <-- temporary-branch
```

(The underlying Git command that produces `I'` from `I` is `git cherry-pick`.  We have to have Git do this on a *temporary branch*, because Git needs to be able to find all the commits, including both the old ones and the new ones being built.  The rebase command hides most of this complexity, but because Git is bad at certain things, sometimes you get to see it all.)

Once Git has copied `I` to `I'`, we need to have Git copy `J` to `J'`:

```
          I--J   <-- your-branch
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- master
              \
               I'-J'  <-- temporary-branch
```

Once *all* the commits that were exclusively on `your-branch` are copied to the new temporary branch, we then have Git "peel the branch name" `your-branch` off commit `J` and paste it onto commit `J'`—the last copy Git just made—and throw out the temporary name:

```
          I--J   [abandoned]
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- master
              \
               I'-J'  <-- your-branch
```

Because Git *finds* commits by branch name, if we look at this repository now, it will seem as though we waited until commit `L` existed, and only then began working and producing commits `I-J`.  We'll see commits `I'` and `J'`, not `I` and `J`, but unless we memorize the actual hash IDs—and *no human ever does that*—we *won't notice* that we're now looking at two different commits.  (Git will know.  Git looks at the raw hash IDs.  But we will forget, because that's what humans do.)

#### Whether and when to rebase is up to you

Because rebase *replaces the old commits with new ones* (new and supposedly improved), it's not always appropriate.  In particular, if you've already given your `I` and `J` commits to *someone else*, and they are *depending on them*—including their hash IDs—then saying "throw those away, use these new and improved ones instead" makes them do extra work.  Sometimes that's fine.  (It's OK if they've already agreed to do that, for instance.)  Sometimes it's not.

If you *have never given these commits to anyone else*, though, they won't ever even *know* you did this.  So for that particular case—"private" commits—it's safe to rebase, as long as you know what you're doing.

The plus to rebasing is that, in the end, the Git history "looks simpler" and people can think about it with less mental load.  The minus is that it's not what really happened: if you break something during a rebase, it can be hard to debug, and it's a lie.  Is it a little white lie that makes things better, or is it a big ugly lie that causes death and destruction?  We don't know, and you might not know *yet*, until you try it out.

Comment: my qustion is, if its possible to merge the branch on commit J to the commit in master on comit H, the rebase is putting the branch above of the head of master

Comment: That question does not make sense. Merging is about combining changes. Commit H has no changes from commit H.

Comment: maybe merging is wrong word, but is it possible to do such work?

Comment: As I wrote (and omer blechman commented), you can *throw away* the other person's work and then your commits extend `master`. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: no throwing away work, is dangerous XD

Comment: In that case, you're back to either merge or rebase, as the two normal ways to *combine* work. Merge works as I described, by literally combining work.